# Enviar plain text con retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, json, retrofit

```
{ Cliente_ID: 1, Nombre_Usuario: "dsadsadsa"}
```

el problema es que la api recibe texto plano, trate de usar retrofit de la siguiente manera:

> Interface

```
@POST("Cliente")
Call<Client> newClient(@Body Client client);
```

> Model

```
@SerializedName("Cliente_ID")
@Expose
private Integer clienteID;
@SerializedName("Nombre_Usuario")
@Expose
private String nombreUsuario;
contruct.. gets.sets..
```

Configuración de retrofit

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseurl)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

Usando postman me di cuenta que al tratar de enviar los valores de al inicio de esta pregunta como `JSON (application/json)` no me los acepta, solo acepta `Text (text/plain)` son bastantes parametros los que debo enviar, alguna solución ante esto? *como configuro retrofit para que envie los parametros en texto plano, pero en formato JSON? ...*

Answer (score 1):

¿Has intentado usando RequestBody?

```
String text = "plain text request body";  
RequestBody body=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), text);
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getStringRequestBody(body);  
Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();  
String value = response.body().string();
```

Puedes obtener más información aquí: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-send-plain-text-request-body

Saludos

Comment: pero no me permite pasar el modelo en RequestBody, que podría hacer ahi?